# Cover whole page with squares arranged in a “spiral”

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, loops

I'm trying to cover a whole landscape A4 paper with small squares – drawn in TikZ – starting from the bottom left corner of the page and moving towards to the center of the page in a spiral, but I have a flaw in my method, because the page is not filled at the end.

[image]

Each small square has a side length of 1.5 mm. And there are a few prerequisites that have to be met, so the page can be fully covered with squares.

1. The width and height of the page (297 mm × 210 mm) has to divisible with the side length of the square.

   210 mod 1.5 = 0

   297 mod 1.5 = 0
2. The area of the page has to be disivble with the area of the square.

   297 mm × 210 mm = 62370 mm<sup>2</sup>

   1.5 mm × 1.5 mm = 2.25 mm<sup>2</sup>

   62370 mod 2.25 = 0

And I have to iterate 62370 / 2.25 = 27720 times to cover the page. All conditions are met, so my algorithm is not correct. (Note that the following code needs to be compiled twice with `lualatex` and this takes about 2 minutes on an older i7 CPU.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nohead,%
    nofoot,%
    nomarginpar,%
    paperwidth=297mm,%
    paperheight=210mm,%
    tmargin=5mm,%
    rmargin=5mm,%
    bmargin=5mm,%
    lmargin=5mm,%
    vscale=1,%
    hscale=1]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{luacode}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{luacode*}
    function square_spiral()
        local direction = 0
        local x = 0
        local y = 0
        local shift = 1.5
        local x_min = 0
        local y_min = shift
        local x_max = 297 - 1.5 * shift
        local y_max = 210 - 1.5 * shift
        local square_count = (297 * 210) / (1.5 * 1.5)

        tex.sprint("\\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]")

        for i = 1, square_count, 1 do

            tex.sprint("\\filldraw[black!" .. (i - 1) / (square_count - 1) * 100 ..
                ", line width=0pt] (current page.south west) ++(" ..
                string.format("%.1f", x) .. "mm, " .. string.format("%.1f", y) ..
                "mm) rectangle +(" .. shift .. "mm, " .. shift .. "mm);")

            if direction == 0 then -- right
                if x < x_max then
                    x = x + shift
                else
                    direction = 1
                    x_max = x_max - shift
                end
            elseif direction == 1 then -- up
                if y < y_max then
                    y = y + shift
                else
                    direction = 2
                    y_max = y_max - shift
                end
            elseif direction == 2 then -- left
                if x > x_min then
                    x = x - shift
                else
                    direction = 3
                    x_min = x_min + shift
                end
            elseif direction == 3 then -- down
                if y > y_min then
                    y = y - shift
                else
                    direction = 0
                    y_min = y_min + shift
                end
            end

            --[[
            print(string.format("%.1f", x) .. ", " ..
                string.format("%.1f", y) .. ", " .. i)
            ]]

        end

        tex.sprint("\\end{tikzpicture}")
    end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}

\luadirect{square_spiral()}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't just due to rounding errors? That is, that TeX will store those numbers in ways which may not be *quite* equivalent to the values you set (e.g. 3 becomes 2.999999...) and that these differences accumulate with the observed results?

Comment: @cfr I use Lua to calculate all coordinates, etc. and then pass the calculated values to TeX with `tex.sprint`, so I don't think that is the issue, but I may be wrong, I'm not sure. If you uncomment the block comment (block comments in Lua start with `--[[` and end with `]]`) towards the end of the `square_spiral` function, the calculated coordinates will be printed to the console during compilation, and there are no accumulating rounding errors. I think my algorithm is missing something (I'm missing something).

Comment: I'm sure you're right. I don't know anything about using Lua. It was just a thought. Sorry if it was off base.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the problem arises because when the sprial changes direction two squares are drawn at each corner. For example, if the spiral is moving right, when the `x < x_max` condition is not met the direction is changed but the `y` coordinate is not moved up so the next square is drawn in the same place as the last square.

I've corrected this in the code below (with a couple of other hopefully insignificant changes)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nohead,%
    nofoot,%
    nomarginpar,%
    paperwidth=297mm,%
    paperheight=210mm,%
    tmargin=5mm,%
    rmargin=5mm,%
    bmargin=5mm,%
    lmargin=5mm,%
    vscale=1,%
    hscale=1]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{luacode} 

\pagestyle{empty} 

\begin{luacode*}
    function square_spiral()
        local direction = 0 
        local x = 0
        local y = 0
        local shift = 1.5 
        local x_min = 0     
        local y_min = shift  
        local paperwidth = math.floor(tex.dimen["paperwidth"]/65536/2.84526)
        local paperheight = math.floor(tex.dimen["paperheight"]/65536/2.84526)
        local x_max = paperwidth - 1.5*shift   
        local y_max = paperheight - 1.5*shift
        local square_count = (paperwidth)*(paperheight) / (shift*shift)
        tex.sprint("\\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]")

        for i = 1, square_count, 1 do 

            tex.sprint("\\filldraw[black!" .. (i - 1) / (square_count - 1) * 100 ..
                ", line width=0pt] (current page.south west) ++(" ..
                string.format("%.1f", x) .. "mm, " .. string.format("%.1f", y) ..
                "mm) rectangle +(" .. shift .. "mm, " .. shift .. "mm);") 


            if direction == 0 then -- right
                if x < x_max then
                    x = x + shift
                else
                    direction = 1
                    x_max = x_max - shift
                    y = y + shift -- MOVE UP
                end
            elseif direction == 1 then -- up
                if y < y_max then
                    y = y + shift
                else
                    direction = 2
                    y_max = y_max - shift
                    x = x - shift -- MOVE LEFT
                end
            elseif direction == 2 then -- left
                if x > x_min then
                    x = x - shift
                else
                    direction = 3
                    x_min = x_min + shift
                    y = y - shift -- MOVE DOWN
                end
            elseif direction == 3 then -- down
                if y > y_min then
                    y = y - shift
                else
                    direction = 0
                    y_min = y_min + shift
                    x = x + shift -- MOVE RIGHT
                end
            end

            --[[
            print(string.format("%.1f", x) .. ", " ..
                string.format("%.1f", y) .. ", " .. i)
            ]]

        end

        tex.sprint("\\end{tikzpicture}")
    end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
\luadirect{square_spiral()}
\end{document}
```

[image]